# Are these two verilog sentences equivalent, do they take the same cycles?

Tags: if-statement, verilog, fpga

I want to know if these two codes would be doing the same? And what is the practical difference between them? If they are doing the same operation, is the second case faster than the first case?

In the first case, because I have to wait until it comes out to the "cycle statement" to recognize the rising of the flag "modi_varx_f" and "modi_vary_f" in order to "activate" in the next cycle and operate the increase of the variable, then it's slower than to do it at once as in the second case that seems to "activate" and run the operation within the same cycle.

1. First case:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
        modi_varx_f = 0;
        modi_vary_f = 0;
    end
    else if (cond1) begin
        modi_varx_f = 1; // increase variable x on 1.
        modi_vary_f = 1; // add 3'd6 to variable.
    end
end

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst) 
        varx  = 0;
    else if (modi_varx_f)
        varx = varx + 1;
end  

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (~rst) 
        vary  = 0;
    else if (modi_vary_f)
        vary = vary + 3'd6;
end
```

2. Second case:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
        varx = 0;
        vary = 0;
    end
    else if (cond1) begin;
        varx = vary + 1; 
        vary = vary + 3'd6;
    end
end
```

Comment: they are not equivalent because 1) they contain different sets of  shown variables. 2) first sequence has syntactic error (missing 'end'). other than that there is no difference.

Comment: @toolic can you explain what do you mean nonblocking tag??

Comment: Why don't you simulate them with a suitable set of test stimuli and compare the waveforms and other outputs? Also, the nonblocking tag is how you tagged your question when posting it.

Comment: @toolic I'm very sorry, I have fixed the code now. I'm new handling the tools of the forum.

Comment: @Serge I have fixed the code now, sorry for mistakes.

Comment: @nanofarad  I see I will edit the tags, thanks. I will code it properly with a testbench I just wanted to know beforehand the answer to match whatever I find after the testbench.

Comment: last two alway blocks in case 1 can be collapsed in a single always block in case 2 with no functional difference. Both cases, as well as the very first always block, have a mistake: you should use non-blocking assignments there (<=).

Comment: @Serge Interesting, why do you think so? wouldn't it be irrelevant since I'm not seeking the use the non-blocking feature for this.

Comment: all sequential logic should use non-blocking assignments for its outputs. (you use flops in the example, which are sequentials). This is the industry-wide practice related to the correctness of the simulation results. It is a different topic though. You can find may explanations.

Comment: @Serge thank you so much, but one last thing, what if I wan to make a deep operation within the same cycle for example:                                                             else if (cond1) begin;
        varx = vary + 1; 
        vary = vary + 3'd6; varx = vary * 3'd2; varx = varc, var ..... etc etc
    end  In this case I'd need blocking assignments and i read somewhere that once you use blocking in one always is better to keep using the same, i.e not to mix blocking with non-blocking, please correct me. thanks again

Comment: This is a different question about using different assignment types and comments are not the right format to answer it. I believe, it has been answered multiple times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to summarize the comment stream. In general, you can collapse multiple sequential always blocks into one without loosing functionality. I guess that you made a mistake in the second example and used `varx = vary + 1;` while in the first case you used `varx = varx + 1;`. This makes the difference.

However, if the second example uses `varx`, than both are equivalent.

Since you used sequential elements (flops with asynchronous reset) in your examples, you should have used non-blocking assignments there, according to industry-wide practices. And the right answer for collapsing should look like this:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
        varx <= 0;
        vary <= 0;
    end
    else if (cond1) begin;
        varx <= varx + 1; // << varx
        vary <= vary + 3'd6;
    end
end
```